# Link a library to a smart contract only with Solidity and bytecode

Tags: solidity, truffle, contract-deployment, dapp-development, library

I work in Truffle development environment and use Windows PowerShell. My Solidity code is a test code and is simple. There is a library called `Alireza` that just compares two uint values. There is a contract called `B` that just uses the library function to compare two uint values. Now, i need to link `Alireza` to `B`. For that

1. I embedded `using-for` command in `B`.
2. I deployed `Alireza` and got its address.
3. I tried to deploy `B` to create its bytecode. As one expects, the
   deplyoment failed.
4. I embedded `Alireza`'s address to `B`'s bytecode. Because, as i
   searched, it is a way to link.
5. I tried to deploy `B` again and it failed again.

Is this work flow correct? i don't know. So, i intent to try another way that [here](https://dev.to/liamzebedee/how-to-link-libraries-into-solidity-contracts-generated-by-sol-compiler-34b3) mentioned:

1. I tried to embed the hash of `Alireza`'s title or directory to `B`'s
   bytecode. Just like:

   ```
    --$12b85d948918b1e5773c9bc099694fc73b$--
   ```
2. I tried to deploy `B` again and again the deployment failed.

Even, before all ways i mentioned, i deployed `B` without deployment of `Alireza` before that. Because i thought maybe, by this way, the compiler would create the link. But, the below error emerges:

```
Error: B contains unresolved libraries. You must deploy and link the following libraries before you can deploy a new version of B: Alireza
```

Am i in a correct way? Where is my problem? How can i link a library to a contract just by Solidity and contract's bytecode and without node-js? How should i alter my work flow to link?

My whole code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.12;

library Alireza{

    function comparison(uint a, uint b) view public returns(bool){  
        if(a==b){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}

contract B{

    using Alireza for uint;

    function assessment(uint m, uint n) view public returns(bool){
        return m.comparison(n);
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I face-planted on these sorts of errors recently too! Turns out there be additional setup required known as *migrations*...

[Truffle -- Running Migrations -- `deployer.link(library, destinations)`](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations#deployer-link-library-destinations-) section covers how to link libraries and contracts.

### TLDR

**`./migrations/99_link_example.sol`**

```js
const Alireza = artifacts.require("Alireza");
const B = artifacts.require("B");

module.exports = (deployer, _network, accounts) => {
  deployer.deploy(Alireza);
  deployer.link(Alireza, B);
  deployer.deploy(B);
};
```

> The `deployer.link` bit is the *magic* line that allows `B` to make use of `Alireza`

### Bonus Tips

- if ya have a contract requiring parameters within it's constructor, then it is possible to define 'em during the `.deploy` phase
- the *`accounts`* parameter holds an array of test account addresses that may be useful too

**`./contracts/Name.sol`**

```
contract Name {
    address public owner;

    function constructor(address _owner) {
        owner = _owner;
    }
}
```

**`./migrations/2_deploy_name.js`**

```js
const Name = artifacts.require("Name");

module.exports = (deployer, _network, accounts) => {
  deployer.deploy(Name, accounts[0]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just compile the code and deploy contract B, no need to do the link thing.
The library code will copy to contract B automatically by the compiler.

Comment: I tried that but the followed error emerges: `Error: B contains unresolved libraries. You must deploy and link the following libraries before you can deploy a new version of B: Alireza`. It says first a library must be deployed before a contract deployment.